How do I configure Docker containers for Traefik Proxy correctly?
I was trying to test out Traefik Proxy, so I added Traefik labels to an existing Compose file I had for OpenSpeedTest.
version: '3.3'
services:
     speedtest:
          restart: unless-stopped
          container_name: openspeedtest
          labels:
               - "traefik.http.routers.speedtest.rule=Host(`internal.littlebitstudios.com`) && Path(`/speedtest`)"
               - "traefik.http.services.speedtest.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
               - "traefik.http.routers.speedtest.entrypoints=http"
          ports:
               - '3050:3000'
               - '3051:3001'
          image: openspeedtest/latest

Yet with the labels added, going to "internal.littlebitstudios.com/speedtest" doesn't show OpenSpeedTest. I don't know if this question should go here or on Stack Overflow.

docker.sock Access
Have you given the Traefik container access to docker.sock? (see the Quick Start page)
You need to provide Traefik access to the host's docker services, which is typically done by adding -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock or the equivalent in docker-compose.yml:
services:
  traefik:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Docker Provider
Have you enabled monitoring docker containers? (see the Traefik & Docker page).
You need to enable the Docker provider, which differs depending on your configuration (YAML or TOML). It might seem odd to add an empty node, but the presence of this node will enable the functionality.
providers:
  docker: {}

[providers.docker]

You can also do this with a command line argument: --providers.docker=true
Exposed by Default
Another consideration is the providers.docker.exposedByDefault option. The default is true, but if this is false, then each container you'd like to Traefik to consider needs to have the traefik.enable=true label.
Docker Network
Finally, if Traefik is appearing to handle the request, but you're getting errors (e.g: HTTP 504 / Gateway Timeout), then you need to make sure that A) the container and Traefik share a common network, and B) you may need to explicitly declare which network to use.
Use the traefik.docker.network label for a container to give it explicitly or override this.
API / Dashboard
If you're still struggling, then the API interface has a dashboard option that can be incredibly useful for figuring out what's going on.
See api.dashboard, enabled by default if you provide the api node (even if empty)
